# Why does the stroke cause my drawable to not render?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

Ok so I have this drawable, it is just a rectangle with a border around it, nothing crazy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="20dp"
        android:color="#76a6ff"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#bad2ff"/>
</shape>
```

and im just setting it as a src in my main activity

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/prog_2"
   android:layout_width="62dp"
   android:layout_height="10dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
   android:src="@drawable/blue_border" />
```

But it wont render. However if I remove this line:

```
android:width="20dp"
```

From the stroke, it renders. If I remove the stroke color, it still wont render. I am really confused why it wouldn't and I do feel like I am overlooking something.

Comment: It isn't simply caused by stroke width exceeding the height of your imageview? Is it rendered for 1 or 2dp?

Comment: Ok update: I moved it to a new project and it rendered? not sure what it was but I saw it on another post. Thank you for your time though